# Weird printing behaviour in Perl

Tags: perl, cygwin

I want to read some numbers from a file into an array and then  print them as part of a statement. But I am getting some weird results. The file `list1.txt` contains the following text:

```
01
02
15
30
43
75
76
```

I want to print:

```
The number is: 01;
The number is: 02;
The number is: 15;
The number is: 30;
The number is: 43;
The number is: 75;
The number is: 76;
```

So I wrote the following simple program:

```
my @arr;
my $i = 0;
open(my $file_fh,"<","list1.txt") or die "Could not find specified file\n";
while (<$file_fh>) {
    $arr[$i] = $_;
    chomp($arr[$i]);
    $i++;
}

foreach my $num (@arr) {
    my $stmt = "The number is: ".$num."\;";
    print "$stmt\n";
}
```

But the result I get is:

```
;he number is: 01
;he number is: 02
;he number is: 15
;he number is: 30
;he number is: 43
;he number is: 75
;he number is: 76
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file you are reading is in Windows format with `CRLF` at the end of each line.  Your cygwin Perl is configured to use Linux line endings, so the `chomp` removes only the ending `LF`, leaving the string value stored with a trailing `CR`, which is causing the semicolon to overwrite the first character of the output.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html ... open($fh,"<:crlf", "my.txt"); # support platform-native and CRLF text files

Comment: s/\s+\z// is better than :crlf because it removes all trailing whitespace, not just CR.

Comment: @ikegami: Maybe; it depends on the situation. The OP just wanted something like `chomp` that actually works, not more.

Comment: @musiphil,  Is that so? Name me one text format that relies on trailing whitespace. If there is one, someone ought to be shot.

Comment: @ikegami: I'm not making any further assumption on the text format other than the fact that each line is terminated by a predefined sequence of characters (`\n`, `\r\n` or `\r`). There may be cases where trailing whitespaces are significant, though I admit that such cases are not very common. And I believe it's best in general to make the fewest assumptions about the input and to make your program work without problems on the widest range of input. I don't want my `cat` (or even `nl`) to remove trailing whitespaces by default.

Comment: @musiphil, We both made one assumption. Mine's the one that helps in every single instance you can think of. Yours is the one that fails in general. Yours is also the one that fails in this case. There's no reason to believe the OP wants to print `The number is: 01___________;` instead of `The number is: 01;`.

Comment: @ikegami: I believe removing trailing whitespaces is what the OP wanted in this case, but I disagree that it holds _in every single instance_. Does your `cat`, `nl`, `head`, `sort`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk` or any of your _general-purpose_ text utility do that by default? If you still believe they should remove trailing whitespaces by default, then we'll have to agree to disagree. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're reading a Windows text file (CRLF line endings) using a Perl on a unix (cygwin) system. Unix systems expect text files to have LF endings.

The fix is to use `s/\s+\z//` instead of `chomp`.

Comment: Thanks for telling me the problem and providing the solution as well

Comment: Maybe _a_ fix, not _the_ fix. `chomp` is meant to remove just the line ending (`$/`), never more, and the problem is that `$/` doesn't match the actual line ending characters. _The_ fix would be to match them by `:crlf` (in `open` or `binmode` or `PERLIO`).

Comment: @musiphil, My fix is better than that because it removes trailing white space too.

Comment: @ikegami: My point is that removing trailing whitespaces other than the newline may not always be desired, and that you cannot claim removing them is better in general. Of course, your fix may be what you want in your situation.

Comment: @musiphil, I can very easily claim it's better in general, and I can very easily back that up. For each text file format that you can name that's sensitive to trailing whitespace, I'll name 5 that aren't.

Comment: @ikegami: I'm not talking about any particular data format; I'm talking about processing text _in general_. Please see my comment in the other answer.